# Proper pasting from clipboard doesn't work in st (simple terminal)

Tags: terminal, vim, clipboard

***If you are wondering you had seen the same question on r/suckless on reddit, I am the same person and upon getting no satisfactory answer I decided to post it here.***

I am trying to patch st to have scrollback functionality. I went to the download page and copied the code(saving the page causes it to be saved with a `mhtml` extension), opened up vim in st and tried to paste it to a newly created diff file but all sorts of weird things happen; multiple braces appear at the end of file, weird indents appear in places, sometimes the `+` and `-` at the start of line are skipped and no syntax highlighting happens(even though it is turned on).

On the other hand, everything works perfectly in termite(highlighting also occurs).

Comment: Did you run `:set paste on` in vim before doing the paste?

Comment: @icarus Thanks! doing that works. Can you please write an answer to why that works and why i have to do that manually in st while termite worked fine?

Comment: To be precise, when working with vim in termite `set paste ?` returns `nopaste`; same as in st. But when I am pasting it is working fine in termite automatically while i have to set it manually in st